# How to make a Button align to the right in a layout?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-linearlayout

I have a custom ListItem row that has a TextView on the top and a TextView on the bottom. I would like to create a Button that is right aligned, and in centered vertically. How can I do this in XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:textSize="18sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textSize="15sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you want the button between the textviews? overlapping the textviews? to the right of the textviews?

Comment: to the right of the textviews

Comment: thats what my proposed layout does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was thinking he wanted something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/TextLayout">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/toptext" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:background="#FFAABB" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textSize="15sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#FFBBAACC" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `android:gravity` or `setGravity(int)`

> Specifies how to place the content of an object, both on the x- and y-axis, within the object itself.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:gravity

specifically for this case, `right|center_vertical`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="text centered"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:text="text to the left"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:text="the button is at the right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think he wants the button centered not the contents of the button

Comment: @jkhouw1 it only depends where you add the gravity. See a full example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use RelativeLayout try

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

That works for me but took a lot of tweaking to get right.

And you also may need

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with something similar to the following:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toptext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:textSize="18sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textSize="15sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This displays the button on the bottom of the textviews and it is aligned left.